# Hi, can you help me to plot a sine wave by the below code for OpenModelica

Tags: waveform, openmodelica

```
model ElectricField2
     Real Eta=377;
     Real Jso=2.58*10^1;
     Real Hy;
     Real P;
     Real Px;
     Real w=12.56*(10^9);
     Real Ex;
     Real f;
protected
     constant Real pi=Modelica.Constants.pi;

equation


     Ex=(Eta*Jso*cos(w*time))/2;
     Hy=(-1*(Jso*cos(w*time)))/2;
     P=Ex*Hy;
     Px=(Eta*((Jso)^2)*(cos(w*time))^2)/2;
     f=w/(2*pi);

end ElectricField2;{I am tring }
```

I am trying to generate a Electric field signal as sine wave and I am not getting it can you give me what should I do to generate the sine wave??